# Gradle plugin as dependency to another module

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Here is the structure:

```
/root
   /plugin
   /sample
```

Is it possible somehow to add locally the plugin as a dependency plugin to the sample?

So assuming that the plugin creates a plugin with the id `my.example.android:1.0` I want to use the following to the sample project:

`apply plugin 'my.example.android`

Answer (score 0):

You can do buildscript "../plugin/plugin.gradle", if it's a simple gradle script.  If it is standalone then you need to publish to a repo and do the builscript + apply statements.